# SSE: unexpected MIME type error

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I am using a PHP file as a worker for a SSE connection. This is my PHP file:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$mysqli = new mysqli(* data *);
$listings = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id FROM listings WHERE schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'");

$to_check = array();
while ($li = $listings->fetch_array()) {
    $to_check[] = array($li["listing_id"], $li["price"], $li["buyer_id"]);
}

while (true) {
    $change = 0;
    $listings_2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id FROM listings WHERE schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'");
    $different = array();
    while ($li_2 = $listings_2->fetch_array()) {
        foreach ($to_check as &$li_check) {
            if ($li_check[0] === $li_2["listing_id"]) {
                if (intval($li_2["price"]) !== intval($li_check[1])) {
                    $li_check = array($li_2["listing_id"], $li_2["price"], $li_2["buyer_id"]);
                    $different[] = $li_check;
                    $change = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($change === 1) {
        echo "data: " . json_encode($different) . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
        flush();
    }
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Even though there is the header that specifies the content-type, I receive an error when I try to use the file:
EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.
I don't receive that error, anyway, when I am using the following code for the same file (commenting the infinite while loop).

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$mysqli = new mysqli(* data *);
$listings = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id FROM listings WHERE schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'");

$to_check = array();
while ($li = $listings->fetch_array()) {
    $to_check[] = array($li["listing_id"], $li["price"], $li["buyer_id"]);
}

/*while (true) {
    $change = 0;
    $listings_2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id FROM listings WHERE schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'");
    $different = array();
    while ($li_2 = $listings_2->fetch_array()) {
        foreach ($to_check as &$li_check) {
            if ($li_check[0] === $li_2["listing_id"]) {
                if (intval($li_2["price"]) !== intval($li_check[1])) {
                    $li_check = array($li_2["listing_id"], $li_2["price"], $li_2["buyer_id"]);
                    $different[] = $li_check;
                    $change = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($change === 1) {
        echo "data: " . json_encode($different) . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
        flush();
    }
    sleep(1);
}*/

echo "data: " . json_encode($different) . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
flush();

?>
```

I can't understand why it happens.

Comment: Have you tried using curl to hit your source to see what the server is returning?

Answer (score 0):

The SSE standard clearly states that if the response does *not* contain text/event-stream, it *MUST* error the connection.

> HTTP 200 OK responses that have a Content-Type other than text/event-stream (or some other supported type) must cause the user agent to fail the connection.

[SSE protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-eventsource-20090421/#processing-model)